# StratifiedKFold: shuffle and random_state

Tags: python, scikit-learn, shuffle

I've done the following for cross-validation purpose:

```
from sklearn.cross_validation import StratifiedKFold
n_folds = 5
SKFolds = list(StratifiedKFold(ytrain, n_folds, shuffle=True))
```

I'm just thinking about one detail: I'd like to have the same final results if somebody (my teacher for instance!) run again the code. However, I forgot to specify the random_state parameter! And I unfortunately can't start again from the begining because my models need a very long time to be fitted and it's quite finished.

My question is the following: is it possible to find what was the random_state which leads to my SKFolds? (my notebook is still opened so maybe the information can be found somewhere?). Or can I do something like save my SKFolds in a csv file and then load it when I will restart my notebook to be sure that I will have the same split on my folds?

Thanks for your help!

Comment: It's probably easier (and cleaner) to save your folds to disk. If you have some kind of ID per data point, then you can store the sampling using only those.

Comment: You could seed the random number generator with a fixed constant.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can save `SKFolds` object with `pickle` and then you will just have to load it and use it as is.

```
import cPickle as pickle

# To save the object
pickle.dump( SKFolds , open( "skfolds.p", "wb" ) )

# To load the object
SKFolds = pickle.load( open( "skfolds.p", "rb" ) )
```

Comment: Thanks a lot for this solution!